# How to delete empty td's on browser

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy

I am iterating a array list in gsp of groovy with grails, if any sub string present in the existing list don't display them on browser, other wise display them. For this i am getting output properly but I am getting empty td's on browser if the string doesn't displaying on the browser then it will shows as a empty td on the browser, so I want to delete that empty td's using jquery or html, please help me, how to solve this error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are just looking to delete empty TD's, you can use the jQuery selector `:empty`:

```
$('td:empty').remove();
```

Note that it doesn't match td's with whitespace.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/S2vxr/